# I am getting ValueError: could not convert string to float. Can anyone please edit this?

Tags: python, tkinter, jupyter-notebook

I am trying this but I am having this constant error Error: could not convert string to float. I searched and couldn't find a solution to this. I don t know where I went wrong. The value from the user which we are trying to get is the problem always. Anyone please help?

```
nn1 = 0
nn2 = 0
n = 0 

from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Rectangles")

def get_ab(event):

    global nn1
    global nn2
    global n


    nn1 = float(nn1Entry.get())
    nn2 = float(nn2Entry.get())
    n = int(n3Entry.get())


button1 = Button(text="Submit")
button1.grid(column=1,row=3)
button1.bind("<Button-1>", get_ab)

label_1 = Label(root, text="Size Of Sheet")
nn1Entry = Entry(root)
nn2Entry = Entry(root)

label_1.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
nn1Entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
nn2Entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

label_2 = Label(root, text="Number of rectangles")
label_2.grid(row=2)
n3Entry = Entry(root)
n3Entry.grid(row=2,column=1)

root.mainloop()

k = n

for i in range(1,k*2+1):
     globals()['b%s' % i]=0

window = Tk()
window.title("Sizes of rectangles")

for i in range(1, k*2+1):
    nEntry = Entry(window)
    nEntry.grid(row=1, column=1)
    a = float(nEntry.get()) #Errorline is this one
    globals()['b%s' % i] = a

window.mainloop()

print(b1)
```

Error line is indicated

Comment: just off the top of my head, its probably because the value you are passing to `float` is empty string `""` and float cant handle that. make sure your text field isn't empty before trying to convert it

Comment: how do i do that? I am actually new to this

Comment: You have lack of understanding how **event driven programming** works. First you have to understand [Event-Driven Programming](http://eventdrivenpgm.sourceforge.net/), [Creating a gui around a python script using Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589817/creating-a-gui-around-a-python-script-using-tkinter/3589984#3589984)

Comment: `if not nEntry.get() == "":
        a = float(nEntry.get())
        globals()['b%s' % i] = a`

Comment: `globals()['b%s' % i] = a` *why* would you do this? just use a dictionary!

Answer (score 0):

As @Nullman said, when you execute the statement `a = float(nEntry.get())`, `nEntry.get()` returned empty string.

Suggest to use `DoubleVar()`:

```
for i in range(1, k*2+1):
    var = DoubleVar()
    globals()['b%s' % i] = var
    Entry(textvariable=var).pack()
```

Then get the result using `DoubleVar.get()`:

```
print(b1.get())
```

In case you want to use `b1` (`b2`, ...) as simple float number, try the following suggestion:

```
def var_trace(name, *args):
    i, var = vars[name]
    try:
        value = var.get()
    except:
        value = 0.0
    globals()['b%s' % i] = value

vars = {}
for i in range(1, k*2+1):
    var = DoubleVar()
    name = '%s' % var # get the internal name of DoubleVar
    vars[name] = (i, var)
    var.trace('w', var_trace) # var_trace will be executed whenever the variable is changed
    var.set(0.0)
    Entry(textvariable=var).pack()
```

Then, you can get the value of `b1` (`b2`, ...) directly:

```
print(b1)
```